# Ubuntu + XFCE + the Albatross theme

Tags: 10.04, themes, xfce

I like the look of this theme:

http://shimmerproject.org/project/albatross/

But I can't figure out how to get xfce to look like this.

Help!

Comment: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Albatross?content=123952

Comment: That's theme from Xubuntu  9.10 -Albatross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the theme from [Github](https://github.com/shimmerproject/Albatross)

And follow [this instructions](http://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes) to install it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Oops, didn't knew that. Thanks.